# How to prevent asp:FormView from rendering as a table?

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have an asp:FormView with an ItemTemplate. I'd like to design the content within the FormView with some div elements:

```
<asp:FormView ID="MyFormView" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="block1">
            Stuff...
        </div>
        <div class="block2">
            Stuff...
        </div>

        ...

        <div class="blockN">
            Stuff...
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

When I run the application the following HTML is created:

```
<table id="MyFormView" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="block1">
                    Stuff...
                </div>
                <div class="block2">
                    Stuff...
                </div>

                ...

                <div class="blockN">
                    Stuff...
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Actually the table is somewhat disturbing. I don't know what's the purpose to have an ItemTemplate to freestyle the content but then wrap it into a table.

Is it possible to disable or work around this behaviour? (I couldn't find a flag in the FormView properties.)

Comment: Would a ListView be useful here? You have more control over the LayoutTemplate.

Comment: If there are not other way I might consider this. I have only one object to display in a form, not a list. So the most "natural" control seemed to be a FormView at a first glance. Anyway, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use repeater (it is light version and fully customizable)

```
  <asp:Repeater runat=server ID="r1">
<HeaderTemplate><div></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>Zzz</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></div></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

or

better use control [adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx):

Comment: Hm, what do you mean with the first option ("use your (div) templates")? Your markup example is exactly what I am doing, am I not?

Comment: I am sorry. I recommend you using Repeater

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It is possible to tell the FormView to stop rendering as a `table` (in ASP.NET 4.0)

Comment: @Kit Roed thanks for information. will learn. at that moment i had not known that. btw downvoting is a bad luck. :) and you cannot see asp.net 4.0 in tags. be more polite.

Comment: Well now I feel sufficiently guilty.  Update your answer and I can change my rash vote.

Comment: @KitRoed: I asked the question before .NET4.0 came out. At that time it was the only answer for several months. No better solution was available before .NET4. Considering this, a downvote is not justified in my opinion. A comment pointing to the new options in .NET 4 is OK though.

Comment: @Slauma as I said in my previous post, please update your answer to be current and the system will let me remove my downvote (and I'll likely even upvote it!)

Answer (score 64):

You can set `RenderOuterTable="false"` on the FormView

Comment: fyi, this is new in ASP.NET 4.0  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032410-1.aspx

Comment: The style property 'Width' cannot be used while RenderOuterTable is disabled on the FormView control

Comment: Can this be used with asp:gridview ?

Answer (score 10):

Use the following code.

```
RenderOuterTable="false"
```

Put it on the *FormView*. It works in .NET 4.0.